# App not showing up in "Open With" menu for supported document type

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder, uti

I have defined the UTIs my app supports, and can drag them onto the Dock icon. I've also implemented -application:openFiles: and -application:openFile: in my app delegate. But when I get info on an item of a UTI I support, it doesn't show up in the list, and is grayed out when I browse to "other". I've pasted a sample UTI from my plist below. What could I be doing wrong? I especially want it to work with the built-in App Store integration.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>cbz</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>CBZ</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Comic Book Zip Archive</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.abbey-code.cbz-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.zip-archive</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Comic Book Zip Archive</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>CBZ</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.abbey-code.cbz-archive</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>cbz</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**Update**

I fired up a VM with no third party applications other than my own installed, and everything is working as expected there. I've rebuilt my LaunchServices database like so:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.fra‌​mework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user ; killall Dock
```

And that made no difference. I then made a dump of the LaunchServices database using this command, with results for my app bundle below it. It looks reasonable to me, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Is it possible I'm experiencing some type of collision with the other apps on my system? If so, how would I resolve that?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.fra‌​mework/Support/lsregister -dump >>lsregister.txt
```

The dump:

```
bundle  id:            61808
    path:          /Applications/AppName.app
    name:          AppName
    category:      public.app-category.entertainment
    identifier:    com.abbey-code.AppName (0x800183e0)
    canonical id:  com.abbey-code.appName (0x8001a08d)
    version:       6433.0
    mod date:      5/6/2014 22:54:46
    reg date:      5/7/2014 9:04:25
    type code:     'APPL'
    creator code:  '????'
    sys version:   10.9
    exec sdk ver:  10.9
    exec os ver:   10.9
    flags:         relative-icon-path  
    item flags:    container  package  application  extension-hidden  native-app  x86_64  
    hi res:        is-capabile  is-explicit  user-can-change  
    app nap:       is-capabile  
    icon:          Contents/Resources/AppIcon.icns
    executable:    Contents/MacOS/AppName
    inode:         37029967
    exec inode:    37030002
    container id:  32
    library:       Contents/Library/
    library items: QuickLook/AppNameQL.qlgenerator/
    --------------------------------------------------------
    type    id:            46888
        bindableKey:   3266
        generation:    7459
        uti:           com.abbey-code.cbz-archive
        description:   Comic Book Zip Archive
        flags:         exported  active  trusted  
        icon:          Contents/Resources/CBZ.icns
        conforms to:   public.zip-archive, public.data
        tags:          .cbz
    --------------------------------------------------------
    type    id:            46932
        bindableKey:   3267
        generation:    7459
        uti:           com.abbey-code.cbr-archive
        description:   Comic Book RAR Archive
        flags:         exported  active  trusted  
        icon:          Contents/Resources/CBR.icns
        conforms to:   public.archive, public.data
        tags:          .cbr
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            37936
        bindableKey:   3268
        generation:    7459
        name:          Comic Book Zip Archive
        rank:          Owner
        roles:         Editor  
        flags:         relative-icon-path  
        icon:          Contents/Resources/CBZ.icns
        bindings:      com.abbey-code.cbz-archive
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            37972
        bindableKey:   3269
        generation:    7459
        name:          Comic Book RAR Archive
        rank:          Owner
        roles:         Editor  
        flags:         relative-icon-path  
        icon:          Contents/Resources/CBR.icns
        bindings:      com.abbey-code.cbr-archive
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            38008
        bindableKey:   3270
        generation:    1
        name:          PDF Document
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         
        icon:          
        bindings:      .pdf
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            38044
        bindableKey:   3271
        generation:    1
        name:          RAR Archive
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         
        icon:          
        bindings:      .rar
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            38080
        bindableKey:   3272
        generation:    1
        name:          ZIP Archive
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Editor  
        flags:         
        icon:          
        bindings:      .zip
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            38116
        bindableKey:   3273
        generation:    7459
        name:          
        rank:          Default
        roles:         QLGenerator  
        flags:         
        icon:          
        delegate:      QuickLook/AppNameQL.qlgenerator/
        bindings:      com.abbey-code.cbz-archive, com.abbey-code.cbr-archive
```

Comment: Have you created an executable and copied it to Finder? It sometimes takes some jumping up and down, waving and secret incantations to make Finder register the types of new apps. Usually copying it to the Desktop does the trick, though..

Comment: @cacau I haven't tried the desktop, but I've installed it in the `Applications` directory and run it from there. What troubles me most is that even when I browse in the "Other…" window, it shows up grayed out.

Comment: One thing to try is rebuilding the launch services DB, it might just happen to be screwed up or keeping an old/incorrect value for your app.

Comment: @cacau Nope. Rebuilt launch services DB and there is no difference. For those following at home, I rebuilt (on Mavericks) with this command: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user ; killall Dock`

Comment: You could also "lsregister -dump >> lsregister.txt" to capture the database in a form that can be searched in a text editor and double check that what's there is what you expect.

Comment: @geowar Thanks, I added the dump for my app bundle to the question. It looks right to me, though. I also added that everything is working fine on a VM I created that doesn't have any other third-party apps installed.

Comment: I'd look for other apps in the db that are using the same public.filename-extension.

Comment: @geowar There certainly others that use the CBR and CBZ exceptions. I even see 2 or 3 of them for each of those extensions currently in "Open With", and they coexist fine. What else might I be looking for?

Comment: Off the top of my (bald) head I'm out of ideas… I'd send this question to Apple's Developer Technical Support (DTS) group for an "official" answer: <https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#requestTechSupport>

Comment: @geowar Thanks for the help. I cross-posted on the dev forums initially, and if I don't hear back from that soon I'll send it on to DTS. Thanks again.

Comment: What UTI do other apps associate with the file extension? Perhaps you should be importing that UTI rather than exporting your own. I think the issue is that Launch Services uses the file extension to figure out a UTI for a file. It picks only one. Then, it looks for apps which handle that UTI. At that point, it doesn't matter that your app can handle files with the extension. It doesn't handle the UTI that Launch Services picked. The description from the selected UTI will be used for the file "kind". If yours is distinct, that's one way to tell which UTI was picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your application to be the one to be launched by default for a specific document type in code. I've found this to be necessary in some cases where setting the link in the info.plist was not sufficient.
This would typically be in the +initialize method of you app controller:

```
    //First Check if our app is the default application to open .cbz files
NSString *cbzUTI = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
                                                                                          (CFStringRef)@"cbz",
                                                                                          NULL));
NSString *currentCbzApp = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(LSCopyDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType((__bridge CFStringRef)cbzUTI, kLSRolesAll));

if ([currentCbzApp caseInsensitiveCompare:@"com.abbey-code.AppName"] != NSOrderedSame) {
    //If not, then first register it in Launch Services
    LSRegisterURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] executableURL], YES);
    //Second set it as the default handler for the file type
    LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType((__bridge CFStringRef)cbzUTI, kLSRolesAll,(__bridge CFStringRef) [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the user be prompted before making such a change? And is this allowed for a sandboxed app?

Comment: Sure, a NSAlert or any other means to ask the user to set the default app for file types that can be handled by other applications as well. For the sandbox, I'm not using it, so I can't comment there.